# Can we construct a sequence of functions such that...

Tags: real-analysis

Ok guys - so there is a possible hole in an analysis proof of mine. I want to see if I can fix it:

If $f_n:E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an increasing sequence with

\begin{align*}
\left\{\int_Ef_n\right\}&~~\text{is bounded}
\end{align*}

Is it possible to create a sequence $g_n:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, also increasing, but $\textit{non-negative}$, such that $|f_n|\leq g_n$ yet
$$\left\{\int_Eg_n\right\}~~\text{is bounded}$$

Comment: Can $\int_E\max\{f_n,0\}$ or  $\int_E\min\{f_n,0\}$ be infinite? What can be said about $\int_E\min\{f_n,0\}$ as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: I see your point - I ran into this problem as well - i.e. comparing $\int_Ef_n$ with $\int_E|f_n|$. I guess this is a dead end - I'll figure out some other way to attack the problem. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

If $\int |f_1|=\infty$, this is clearly impossible. But under the assumption $\int |f_1|<\infty$ the answer is yes. (Here and below all integrals are over $E$.)

Indeed, the obvious   choice for $g_n$ is $\max_{1\le m\le n}|f_m|$, as this is the smallest function that fits the conditions. Let's use the notation $x^+=\max(x,0)$ and $x^-=\max(-x,0)$. Then $|f_m|=f_m^++f_m^-$. The sequence $(f_m^+) $ is increasing and the sequence $(f_m^-)$ is decreasing. Thus, $g_n\le f_n^++ f_1^-$. The integral of $f_1^-$ is finite  by assumption.  The integral of $f_n^+$ is estimated as 
$$\int f_n^+ = \int f_n + 2\int f_n^- \le \int f_n + 2\int f_1^-$$
where the right hand side is bounded.